# Как удалить слово из файла

Tags: java

Программа находит длинное слово в файле, подскажите как его можно удалить?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class WordFinder {
     public static void main(String [ ] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    new WordFinder().getLongestWord();
 }

public String getLongestWord() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String longestWord = "";
    String current;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        current = scan.next();
        if (current.length() > longestWord.length()) {
            longestWord = current;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(longestWord);
            return longestWord;
        }
}
```

Comment: что на счет того, чтобы создать новый файл и записать туда все, что надо?

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант решения. Для простоты понимания я разбил единый свой код на методы.

В методе `findLongestString` - мы берем имя файла, сканируем его и с помощью сравнения длины строк (`if (longest.length() < currentWord.length())`) находим самое длинное слово. Если таких длинных слов 2 или более - программа возвращает значение только первого большого слова, попавшегося на пути. После возврата значения `return longest` мы присваиваем полученное слово переменной `longest` в `main`-методе, чтобы в дальнейшем использовать его в другом методе (мог сделать через глобальную переменную вместо локальной сделать, но так не интересно было бы:) )

В методе `deleteWord` я беру полученное длинное слово и имя файла. Далее я создаю считывание файла и запись файла (потому что в Java я, лично, не знаю другого способа замены/удаления строк). Зачем мне нужны эти две вещи? Я считываю файл, в котором есть длинное слово и если строка не является тем словом, я записываю данные во временный файл `temp.txt`, если является - я пропускаю запись данной строки в файл с помощью `continue`. В итоге, после прочтения файла я получил 2 файла - `temp.txt` и `test2.txt` (как у меня в примере). Файл `temp,txt` - новый полученный файл после удаления строки, а `test2.txt` - старый. Что нужно дальше сделать?) Правильно, заменить один файл другим. Делаем это через `tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);`.

В методе `printFile` я просто вывожу на экран файл. Т.к. я записал эту функцию в конце - программа выведет файл `test2.txt` с удаленным длинным словом.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "test2.txt";
        WordFinder wordFinder = new WordFinder();
        String longest = wordFinder.findLongestString(filename);
        wordFinder.deleteWord(longest, filename);
        wordFinder.printFile(filename);

    }

    public String findLongestString(String filename) {
        String longest = "";
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String currentWord = scanner.nextLine();
                if (longest.length() < currentWord.length()) {
                    longest = currentWord;
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return longest;
    }

    public void deleteWord(String longestWord, String filename) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File(filename);
            File tempFile = new File("temp.txt");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(currentLine.equals(longestWord)) 
                        continue;
                writer.write(currentLine+"\n");
            }
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printFile(String filename) {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```